# Why doesn't Butch remove his hat throughout the movie?

Tags: character, django-unchained

Butch Pooch (James Remar) doesn't take his hat off the entire film. Especially in the setting Tarantino places the film in, the character must have a reason; there's nothing absurdist about the film; it still deals within the bounds of reality.

So when Jamie Foxx's character says "You don't wear a hat in the house white man, even I know that." it's not like Butch doesn't know that, right?

He's wearing it in order to be imposing, isn't he? I mean, why wouldn't Candie make him take it off if not because it helped him do what M. Candie hired him to do?

Answer (score -2):

It reminds me specifically of the Pinkertons, and there's no other way to get that *impression*, and only the impression, across. Because the sole distinguishing characteristic of a Pinkerton is their [hat](https://www.google.com/search?q=pinkerton%20hat), which in a few ways resembles Butch's hat. Tarantino would not want to use the actual hat and then be creatively limited by the characteristics, behavior, mores etc of the historical Pinkertons (as he would otherwise feel obliged to do accurately, or at least close to it).

Answer (score -3):

I don't have a source on for this film, but in other movies, such as the Indiana Jones franchise, hats are used so that the film crew doesn't need to worry about maintaining consistency with the lead character hair between shots.

Comment: The very last thing before every single setup is "Final checks!" when costume, hair & makeup come dashing onto the set to make last-minute adjustments to everyone in the shot. If the character's wearing a hat, that's actually twice as much work, because a hat is costume, not hair's responsibility. [Even more fun, a hat is costume - but a helmet is props, so that would be 3 teams all fussing round the same actor.. for every single setup…] BTW, having worked on the last Indiana Jones - not only did they do his hair every time - they took the hat off to do it & put it back on afterwards.

Comment: You're disagreeing with the directors commentary from Raiders of the Lost Ark?

Comment: I'm disagreeing with this as a standard working practise.